# "Occupation" and "professional occupation (plus calling and career)" vs. "vocation" and "professional vocation"

Tags: american-english, word-usage, colloquialisms, malapropisms

Is "professional vocation" an acceptable alternative to "professional occupation", and to "professional calling or career" also?

You might want to consider the following sourced examples for this:

> What is your current vocation? How many years have you been currently involved in... [source](http://www.crossroadscounselinggroup.com/wp-content/uploads/Adult-Client-Self-Report.pdf)
>
> What is your current vocation? High school English teacher at Westfield High.
>   [source](http://www.indwes.edu/Academics/JWHC/Alumni-Newsletter-Advent-2012/)
>
> While her vocation is teaching school, one of her hobbies is baking amd more often than not she makes cookies. [source](http://www.newspapers.com/newspage/17115621/)
>
> John began his professional vocation as a teacher. [source](http://www.adams.edu/news/may0821.php)
>
> Johann Graff started his professional vocation as a butcher...[source](http://www.worldsrichpeople.com/johann-graf.html)
>
> Mickey Cottrell (Producer) began his professional career as a repertory actor.[source](http://www.grady.uga.edu/osbornefest/images/photo06/Guests/Mickey%20Cottrell%20Producer%20Bio.doc)
>
> Judge Ramirez began his professional vocation as a civil servant, commencing his career as an attorney...[source](http://www.co.hidalgo.tx.us/ArchiveCenter/ViewFile/Item/581)

If indeed "vocation" is a valid option to meaning "a specified occupation, profession, or trade", and to "a calling or career" also, is any ambiguity unlikely with its second meaning, i.e. "a certain feeling of suitability for a particular career or occupation"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Vocation", "occupation", and "career" -- and "job" I might add -- all mean basically the same thing. You can make subtle distinctions between them.

Sometimes "vocation" and "calling" are used to convey the idea that this is what someone really wants to do, this is their dream or goal, as opposed to an "occupation" which is what they are actually doing right now. Like someone might say, "Right now my occupation is 'waiter', but my real vocation is 'rock star'."

A "job" or "occupation" is typically understood as what you are doing right now, while a "career" is long term. "I am studying for a career in information technology" versus "I just got a job at ABC Company".

Comment: So, does asking "What's your current vocation?" sound like a malapropism to your ear?

Comment: Well ... it would sound odd to me. It could make sense in the right context. Like, "I used to dream of becoming a concert violinist, but I realize that that is just not going to happen." "That's too bad. So what is your current vocation?", meaning, "So what do you plan to do now?" And as I started out, "vocation" can be used as a synonym for "occupation", so it would not be totally off the wall to ask that. But yes, it sounds odd to me.

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a hard-and-fast rule, in colloquial speech (here in New York anyway) vocation tends to refer to the field while occupation refers to the job for example the occupation listed on my tax return is

> Software Developer, *company name here*
>   but my vocation is "Programmer"

To make things more confusing, vocations are sometimes distinguished from professions where professions are "white collar" fields and vocations are what were formerly referred to as "the trades."